# ajax request not working in google chrome - net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a plain html page and I write some javascript code that use jquery ajax request. The ajax request sends to server successfully in firefox and IE, but does not work in google chrome! When the ajax request sent, chrome console shows `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error. I don't know How can I solve this strange problem. Here is my ajax code:

```
var data = {};
data['type'] = "email";
data['value'] = "test@gmail.com"
$.ajax({
   headers: {
      Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
   },
   type: "POST",
   url: "/testUrl",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   async: false,
   success: function(result) {
      alert("success");
   },
   error: function(data) {
      alert("error");
   },
   failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert("failure");
   }
});
```

I tested plain ajax request with `XMLHttpRequest` javascript object, but also has above problem.